# FacebookSDK: Can we add the FBLoginView to UINavigation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, loginview

We can add UIButton to a UINavigation but can we add the FBLoginView instead too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes login is a view so therefore you can. I have done it using ibaction method and within it pushed my view to the controller. That maybe the way for you as well.

Comment: Oh i just realized this isn't what i want. I want to that FBLoginView to a navigation bar. Is ok I found another way. Thanks